# What ways are there to increase travel pace each day for a group exploring?

Tags: dnd-5e, travel, exploration

Lots of answers talk about characters movement speeds. I can't find any useful list of ways to increase travel pace.

I know of the 6th level Totem Warrior Barbarian’s Elk Feature, and Ranger's Natural Explorer Feature.

Are there any others?

Comment: Which part of Natural Explorer are you looking at? While it allows you to be stealthy at a normal pace, and prevents difficult terrain from slowing your pace, I see nothing that actively increases your travel speed

Comment: Your title indicates that you are interested in characters _exploring_ but your body asks about _travel pace_.  Is there a specific activity you want the characters doing besides moving from Point A to Point B?

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 8 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* provides an answer under the Exploration section titled [Special Travel Pace](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#SpecialTravelPace):

> When a creature is traveling with a flying speed or with a speed granted by magic, an engine, or a natural force (such as wind or a water current), translate that speed into travel rates using the following rules:
>
> - In 1 minute, you can move a number of feet equal to your speed times 10.
> - In 1 hour, you can move a number of miles equal to your speed divided by 10.
> - For daily travel, multiply your hourly rate of travel by the number of hours traveled (typically 8 hours).
> - For a fast pace, increase the rate of travel by one-third.
> - For a slow pace, multiply the rate by two-thirds.

Any feature that fits this criteria would also affect your travel pace. Examples provided in the same section include spells such as Phantom Steed and Wind Walk, magical items such as a Carpet of Flying, and vehicles such as a sailboat or steam engine. Where applicable, factors such as wind speed or water currents could also increase travel speed, though these are unlikely to be under consistent player control.

Aside from the options fitting the DMG criteria, the [Marine](https://www.dndbeyond.com/backgrounds/marine) background from *Ghosts of Saltmarsh* provides the Feature: Steady which allows you to "move twice the normal amount of time (up to 16 hours) each day before being subject to the effect of a forced march".

Comment: Welcome to answering on rpg.se. I see that you already took the tour, so if any question about site-workings comes up, don't hesitate to consult the [help] or join us in chat once you have the required reputation. That is a solid answer :)

Answer (score 0):

### There are a variety of options:

1. Mounts and vehicles. Mostly the former if moving through rough terrain.
2. Various magical item - horseshoes of a zephyr for mounts. Broom of flying or carpet of flying (if your DM allows it).
3. Any spell, item or class feature that increases your movement or grants the ability to fly for an extended duration.
4. Using familiars that can fly or move quickly can also allow faster scouting out of the area.

Keep in mind. Increasing a character's speed allows them to travel faster on foot, but without splitting the party, it doesn't help the entire party.